# How to retain maximum valued element

Tags: xslt

Suggest for how to retain only the **maximum** valued element among others. I used static comparing method using xsl:if, is there any other method to do. I coded some variables to store the values, those are required in my live project. Please suggest.

Input XML:

```
<article>

<math>
    <mi>2</mi>
    <mi>3</mi>
</math>

<math>
    <mi>3</mi>
    <mi>2</mi>
    <mi>3</mi>
</math>

<math>
    <mi>3</mi>
    <mi>3</mi>
    <mi>2</mi>
</math>

<math>
    <mi>3</mi>
    <mi>3</mi>
    <mi>3</mi>
</math>

<math>
    <mi>5</mi>
    <mi>5</mi>
    <mi>3</mi>
</math>

<math>
    <mi>3</mi>
    <mi>5</mi>
    <mi>5</mi>
</math>

<math>
    <mi>5</mi>
    <mi>3</mi>
    <mi>5</mi>
</math>

<math>
    <mi>5</mi>
    <mi>1</mi>
    <mi>2</mi>
</math>

<math>
    <mi>5</mi>
    <mi>3</mi>
    <mi>3</mi>
</math>

</article>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mi">
    <xsl:variable name="var1" select="following::text()[normalize-space(.)!=''][1][generate-id(ancestor::math)=generate-id(current()/ancestor::math)]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="var2" select="preceding::text()[normalize-space(.)!=''][1][generate-id(ancestor::math)=generate-id(current()/ancestor::math)]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="var1a" select="following::text()[normalize-space(.)!=''][2][generate-id(ancestor::math)=generate-id(current()/ancestor::math)]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="var2a" select="preceding::text()[normalize-space(.)!=''][2][generate-id(ancestor::math)=generate-id(current()/ancestor::math)]"/>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$vPresent lt $var1 or $vPresent lt $var1a">
            <xsl:comment><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy></xsl:comment>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$vPresent lt $var2 or $vPresent lt $var2a">
            <xsl:comment><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy></xsl:comment>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$vPresent eq $var2 and $vPresent eq $var1a">
            <xsl:comment><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy></xsl:comment>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="not($vPresent eq $var2) and $vPresent eq $var1">
            <xsl:comment><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy></xsl:comment>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Required OutPut:

```
<article>
<math>
    <!--2-->
    <mi>3</mi>
</math>

<math>
    <!--3-->
    <!--2-->
    <mi>3</mi>
</math>

<math>
    <mi>3</mi>
    <!--3-->
    <!--2-->
</math>

<math>
    <!--3-->
    <!--3-->
    <mi>3</mi>
</math>

<math>
    <!--5-->
    <mi>5</mi>
    <!--3-->
</math>

<math>
    <!--3-->
    <!--5-->
    <mi>5</mi>
</math>

<math>
    <!--5-->
    <!--3-->
    <mi>5</mi>
</math>

<math>
    <mi>5</mi>
    <!--1-->
    <!--2-->
</math>

<math>
    <mi>5</mi>
    <!--3-->
    <!--3-->
</math>

</article>
```

Comment: There is a `max` function in XPath 2.0 to compute the maximum of a sequence so you might be able to use that. And a single template which then does an `xsl:choose` to check various conditions of the matched node and define various types of handling usually, in my view, asks for writing various templates with match patterns checking the different conditions.

Comment: "*how to retain only the **maximum** valued element among others.*" There is a difference between (1) retaining only the maximum-valued elements and (2) retaining only one of the maximum-valued elements. Your example seems to request the latter - and it selects the last one among them. Is there any significance to that?

Comment: @michael.hor257k last one is to retain.

Comment: @michael.hor257k just now I altered variables' code to find the value within existing MATH element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="article"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mi[.=max(../mi)][last()]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mi">
    <xsl:comment>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:comment>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for superb suggestion. Please suggest how to check this logic with respect to my Variables method, where I am checking for existence of the MI consecutively. Ex. <math><mi>3</mi><mi>2</mi><mo>+</mo><mi>3</mi><mi>9</mi></math> to be changed as 
<math><mi>3</mi><!--2--><mo>+</mo><!--3--><mi>9</mi></math>

Comment: @RudramuniTP I am afraid I don't follow. What is the advantage of your method? -- P.S. Please don't post code in comments, it is very difficult to read.

Comment: sorry to place the tags in comments block, can I change the input? Please suggest.

Comment: @RudramuniTP, you can edit your question to provide additional input but I would suggest to ask a new question with the new input, it looks as you have a different problem where you might need to use `for-each-group group-adjacent="boolean(self::mi)"` and that way require a different answer.

Comment: @Michael, by the variables I can check the successive existence of MI tags, therefore I used following::text()[normalize-space(.)!=''][1].

Comment: @Michael I will do as suggested.